# What's the act of drawing "squiggles" over something wrong you have written called

Tags: vocabulary

Let's say if I write 2 + 2 = 5 with a pen, and realize that was wrong. What's the act of drawing "squiggles"/lines over the answer called?

Comment: But to be clear, squiggles aren't lines. You should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you draw over something in that sense, you [**cross out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cross%20out) (or are **crossing out**) a mistake:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to draw a line through (something) to show that it is wrong · *cross out* a mistake · He had *crossed* his name *out*.

It doesn't need to be a squiggle; it can be anything that shows you are covering up the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinguish between neat "crossing out" and the messy appearance from drawing lots of "squiggles" you can say "scribble out"

> {teacher} If you make a mistake just take your ruler and draw a line through it. Don't scribble out your mistakes, because that makes your book look messy.